# Creating unique IDs for file geodatabase using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, relationship-class, database-design

I use ArcEditor licence level, ArcGIS 10.0 version, and we're talking about a file geodatabase.

I have several feature classes (electric energy domain) and I want to connect them using relationship classes, so I want to use their ID's as foreign keys.

I want to automatically create a significant unique ID for each feature. It'a a text type ID, which would be composed of two letters and several numbers (ex. CH00123, CH00124). The ID would give me three info : what type of feature we're talking about (channel- CH), on which street it is (00), and it's unique code (123). I don't want to type this code for every feature I create, I need something to automatically assign an ID to each feature.

I am not sure how to handle this situation. Do I need to use a data integration software? an engine to generate my special ID's?

Comment: Have you discovered a solution for this issue yet? We are trying to accomplish the same thing only the data resides in a personal gdb. probably need to convert to file gdb. Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: try using Attribute Assistant the GENERATE-ID method.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create a new field in your feature class and use the [Field Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/) to create the unique ID based on fields in the class. Something like:

```
"CH%s%s" % (!StreetField!, !UniqueCodeField!)
```

using Python.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign IDs (or another field) automatically, you should programmatically create Class Extension that listens to edit events and updates corresponding Id field
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000201000000

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth looking at the Infrastructure Network Editing (ArcGIS 10) to see if the attribute assistant can be configured to create your IDs.  I don't recall if it can be used outside of a network.

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=14bdfb26bc2f4e0388a633fbd0ccca02

[Zip](http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/content/items/14bdfb26bc2f4e0388a633fbd0ccca02/data)

> Infrastructure Network Editing also includes an editor extension
>   called the Attribute Assistant. This extension uses a series of
>   pre-defined methods to automatically populate attributes for you when
>   updating and/or adding new features to the geodatabase.

I previously worked at utility where we did not use Infrastructure Network Editing and instead had custom tools based on [megadrofan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4720/megadrofan)'s approach. We moved the actual ID creation to database stored procs and the extension makes calls to the stored procs for ID values.

Comment: Remark, stored procs are only avaliable in enterprise geodatabases.

Comment: Stored procs are available in the underlying relational database of an ent. gdb OR in a separate database independent of any geodatabase.  So you can edit in pgdbs/fgdbs and still draw your ids from elsewhere (like a stored proc or a web service).

Comment: Sorry, I was inaccurate in term enterprise geodatabase. Of course i meant underlying RDMS.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'll let you know how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use ESRI's Attribute Assistant tool to assist with the auto-generation of unique IDs for each feature class: http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-sequences-and-id/. You can use the generate ID tool and custom logic to create your agency's unique ID.