# Assign unique ID to each polygon

Tags: arcgis-10.0, polygon

I feel like this should be really simple and I am missing something. All I wish to do is assign a unique ID to each polygon since I have multiple identical FID values. In MS excel I would simply type 1 then run this value down the rows of the column and it would automatically assign 1,2,3.....n. Can I do something in Arc10? Thanks

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22979/creating-unique-id-s-for-my-file-geodatabase for a solution.

Answer (score 18):

According to http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/6710-GIVING-SEQUENTIAL-NUMBERS-TO-A-FIELD

Copy the following code to the field calculator code block (python):

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
 pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec
```

Copy this to the window below the code block:

```
autoIncrement()
```

Comment: I have used this piece of code in several different scenarios, absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score -3):

Try this;

1. Right click on the field to be calculated and Choose "Calculate"
2. Type [FID]+1

Comment: This won't create unique IDs since there are "multiple identical FID values" (according to the question).

Comment: By definition, FID's are unique: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37480. If your FID's are not unique, you may have an editing session active, or you are no longer in an ArcGIS environment.

Comment: Agreed that FIDs should be unique in most cases. Presumably something happened to the data in question that has corrupted the FIDs.