# Auto incrementing new column using Field Calculator in QGIS modeler?

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing, vector-grid

I am making a model which requires creating a grid and clipping various layers to it. Using the **Create grid** function does not provide an ID column, instead it creates 2 columns: "longitude" and "latitude".

Because of this, I would like the Modeler to insert a new ID column using either **Field Calculator** or **Advanced Python Field Calculator** but I have no idea what the expression is.

I am using QGIS 2.2.0 Valmiera.

I have noticed this topic: [Auto-incrementing in Python Script with ArcPy cursor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57300/how-can-you-auto-increment-in-a-python-script-not-field-calculator/57412#57412)

If using the **Advanced Python Field Calculator**, would the python coding be inserted to the *Global expression* or to the *Formula*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't need a true, database-style auto-incrementing field (which would only work in PostGIS or Spatialite or another db data format), you could simply add a calculation step to your model, calculating an ID column with the expression:

```
$rownum
```

… this will give a unique, incremented set of integer values.