# Auto Generate Sequential Asset IDs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I am Looking for a python script that will automatically assign a unique sequential value to a field every time a new feature (asset) is created. This ID will also need the abbreviated name prepended to the identifier.

So for example, if I add a new sign (SN) to the signs feature class, I'd like that sign to have an Asset ID of SN235.

Alternatively, I could field calculate each time a new asset or series of assets is added so long as the next feature is given the next sequential value.

I have seen scripts such as this: [Auto-incrementing in Python Script with ArcPy cursor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57300/how-can-you-auto-increment-in-a-python-script-not-field-calculator)

But it isn't quite what I need.

Has anyone created or come across a script that will do this?

Comment: You want it to be automatic, like OnCreateFeature? For how many concurrent users? That's a bit beyond what python can do. What database is your data in? Some databases have 'trigger' functions that can be used to assign a unique ID OnNewRow but to do this in ArcGis I'm fairly sure you will need ArcObjects. The Attribute Assistant mentioned by Midavalo would be an ArcObjects form.

Answer (score 2):

Not a python script, but Esri's [Attribute Assistant](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/tools/) has a tool called [Generate ID](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/tools/attribute-assistant-methods/#generate-id) which will automatically generate a new ID whenever a new feature is created.

These IDs can be created per feature class to generate different IDs for different feature classes, and can be created based on a specific template if required.